# error in JSF deployment with external JAR

Tags: jar, jsf-2.2, wildfly-10

I try to add an **external JAR library** to my JSF project.
My Project structure Looks like this:

- XXX (EAR)
- XXXWeb
- XXXEJB

When I deploy my Project I get the following error from my Wildfly 10.1 console:

```
15:42:52,338 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (default task-185) Failed to define class de.sqs.topInterface.IAPIException in Module "deployment.sqs-selfservice.ear.sqs-selfserviceWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link de/sqs/topInterface/IAPIException (Module "deployment.sqs-selfservice.ear.sqs-selfserviceWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/omg/CORBA/UserException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
15:42:52,338 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-185) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component SQSBean for method public java.lang.String de.ruv.sqs usc.web.beans.SQSBean.connect(): javax.ejb.EJBException: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link de/sqs/topInterface/IAPIException (Module "deployment.sqs-selfservice.ear.sqs-selfserviceWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/omg/CORBA/UserException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at de.ruv.sqsusc.web.beans.SQSBean.connect(SQSBean.java:23)
```

SQSBean.java:

```
import de.ruv.sqs.connector.SQS_Connector;

@Stateless
@Named("sqs")
public class SQSBean {

    public String connect() {
    SQS_Connector sc = new SQS_Connector(); // <<-- 23
    }
}
```

At first I tried to add the libraries to EJB. After that I added it to WEB-INF/lib and to EAR/lib. But the error remains the same.

So where and how do I have to include external JAR library files with a common Software API to have access to them in my JSF Webaplication?

If you have an example or how to, it would be very, very nice!
Thank you!